# Why does my button start automatically and not manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I develop an API with Angular 2 using the Janus media server.

I have a problem with the start button, once I run Janus it starts the button automatically not manually.

This is the function I used:

```
//   Use a button to start the demo
$('#start').click(function() {
  if (started)
    return;
  started = true;
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'true').unbind('click');
  //  Make sure the browser supports WebRTC
  //   if(!Janus.isWebrtcSupported()) {
  //  Janus.log("No WebRTC support... ");
  return;
  // }
});
```

Comment: While I edited the title to match your question in the body it still is very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without Jquery (I assumed this is what you asked for?).

```
  //   Use a button to start the demo
    let start = document.getElementById('#start')
    start.onclick = function() {
        if(started)
            return;
        started = true;

        start.onclick = ''
        start.disabled = true
        //  Make sure the browser supports WebRTC
        //   if(!Janus.isWebrtcSupported()) {
            //  Janus.log("No WebRTC support... ");
         return; 
            // }
    };
```